# how to build a xml file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I have a datatable as shown below

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("region", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("technology", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("sitetype", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("status", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("siteid", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("cellid", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("LONGITUDE", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("LATITUDE", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("SCALE", typeof(double));
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "G", "MACRO", "WORKING", "2330", 23301, 24.4251, 25.6011, 87});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "G", "MACRO", "WORKING", "2330", 23302, 24.4251, 25.6011, 88});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "G", "MACRO", "WORKING", "2330", 23303, 24.4251, 25.6011, 89 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "G", "MACRO", "OTHERS", "2330", 23304, 27.4251, 54.6011, 89 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "G", "MICRO", "WORKING", "2331", 23311, 25.4251, 25.6011, 90 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "G", "INDOOR", "WORKING", "2332", 23321, 26.4251, 25.6011, 87 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "U", "MACRO", "WORKING", "4330", 43301, 37.4251, 25.6011, 82 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "L", "MACRO", "WORKING", "5330", 53301, 19.4251, 15.6011, 80 });
```

,i want to replace the xml placeholders begins with `***` in order to build a well formed xml from the above datatable.
The xml template is as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
 xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:json="http://www.w3.org/2005/Json">
  <Folder>
    <name>***Region***</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Folder>
      <name>***Technology***</name>
      <open>1</open>
      <Folder>
        <name>***SiteType***</name>
        <Folder>
          <name>***STATUS***</name>
          <Document>
            <name>POINTS</name>
            <Placemark>
              <name>***Site Id***</name>
              <description><ul>
   <li>CI = ***CI***
   <li>LONGITUDE = ***LONGITUDE***
   <li>LATITUDE = ***LATITUDE***</ul></li>
              </description>
              <Point>
                <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                <coordinates>***LONGITUDE***,***LATITUDE***,***SCALE***</coordinates>
              </Point>
            </Placemark>
          </Document>
          <Document>
            <name>LINES</name>
            <Style id="Zamoras0_0">
            </Style>
            <Placemark>
              <name>***Site Id***</name>
              <styleUrl>#Zamoras0_0</styleUrl>
              <MultiGeometry>
                <LineString>
                  <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                  <coordinates>***LONGITUDE***,***LATITUDE***,***SCALE***</coordinates>
                </LineString>
              </MultiGeometry>
            </Placemark>
          </Document>
        </Folder>
      </Folder>

    </Folder>
  </Folder>
</kml>
```

The important thing is for each `cellid`**(CI)** coming with same siteid,status,sittype needs to be incremented on both placeholder coming under two `<Document>` section like as below(only document sction i am posting)

```
     <Document>
                    <name>POINTS</name>
//for 23301
                    <Placemark>
                      <name>2330</name>
                      <description><ul>
           <li>CI = 23301
           <li>LONGITUDE = 24.4251
           <li>LATITUDE = 25.6011</ul></li>
                      </description>
                      <Point>
                        <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                        <coordinates>24.4251, 25.6011, 87</coordinates>
                      </Point>
                    </Placemark>
//for 23302
<Placemark>
                      <name>2330</name>
                      <description><ul>
           <li>CI = 23302
           <li>LONGITUDE = 24.4251
           <li>LATITUDE = 25.6011</ul></li>
                      </description>
                      <Point>
                        <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                        <coordinates>24.4251, 25.6011, 87</coordinates>
                      </Point>
                    </Placemark>
                  </Document>
                  <Document>
                    <name>LINES</name>
                    <Style id="Zamoras0_0">
                    </Style>
//for 23301
                    <Placemark>
                      <name>2330</name>
                      <styleUrl>#Zamoras0_0</styleUrl>
                      <MultiGeometry>
                        <LineString>
                          <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                          <coordinates>24.4251, 25.6011, 87</coordinates>
                        </LineString>
                      </MultiGeometry>
                    </Placemark>
//for 23302
<Placemark>
                      <name>2330</name>
                      <styleUrl>#Zamoras0_0</styleUrl>
                      <MultiGeometry>
                        <LineString>
                          <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                          <coordinates>24.4251, 25.6011, 87</coordinates>
                        </LineString>
                      </MultiGeometry>
                    </Placemark>
                  </Document>
```

I am from c++ side, and i really scruewed here,can any one help me
i did like shown below without any luck

**EDIT**
Result should be like as below

```
 <Document>
                        <name>POINTS</name>
    //for 23301
                        <Placemark>
                          <name>2330</name>
                          <description><ul>
               <li>CI = 23301
               <li>LONGITUDE = 24.4251
               <li>LATITUDE = 25.6011</ul></li>
                          </description>
                          <Point>
                            <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                            <coordinates>24.4251, 25.6011, 87</coordinates>
                          </Point>
                        </Placemark>
    //for 23302
    <Placemark>
                          <name>2330</name>
                          <description><ul>
               <li>CI = 23302
               <li>LONGITUDE = 24.4251
               <li>LATITUDE = 25.6011</ul></li>
                          </description>
                          <Point>
                            <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                            <coordinates>24.4251, 25.6011, 87</coordinates>
                          </Point>
                        </Placemark>
                      </Document>
                      <Document>
                        <name>LINES</name>
                        <Style id="Zamoras0_0">
                        </Style>
    //for 23301
                        <Placemark>
                          <name>2330</name>
                          <styleUrl>#Zamoras0_0</styleUrl>
                          <MultiGeometry>
                            <LineString>
                              <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                              <coordinates>24.4251, 25.6011, 87</coordinates>
                            </LineString>
                          </MultiGeometry>
                        </Placemark>
    //for 23302
    <Placemark>
                          <name>2330</name>
                          <styleUrl>#Zamoras0_0</styleUrl>
                          <MultiGeometry>
                            <LineString>
                              <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                              <coordinates>24.4251, 25.6011, 87</coordinates>
                            </LineString>
                          </MultiGeometry>
                        </Placemark>
                      </Document
```

Two `documents`(`Points and Lines`) for each cellids having same status(Here working) and `placemarks` should be incremented simultaneously for each `cellids`

Comment: Try using [DataTable.WriteXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ Sepehr Farshid i am not creating new one,i have xml template which need to be replaced with the data coming from datatable while maintaining the heirarchy

Comment: This is your 3rd posting with the same issue.  Previous postings I supplied code that works.  Why ask the same question again?  It is easy with previous code to increment CI.

Comment: @jdweng the problem with this code is there is only two document section for each status and inside document section each having placemarks which should increment simultaneously for each cellids.Here document is coming outside of status and repeating everytime.Nutshell only two document for each status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't keep on changing the question.  work from previous results.

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
 xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:json="http://www.w3.org/2005/Json">
  <Folder>
    <name>***Region***</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Folder>
      <name>***Technology***</name>
      <open>1</open>
      <Folder>
        <name>***SiteType***</name>
        <Folder>
          <name>***STATUS***</name>
          <Document>
            <name>POINTS</name>
            <Style id="myDefaultStyles">
            </Style>
            <Placemark>
              <name>***SITE ID***</name>
              <styleUrl>#myDefaultStyles</styleUrl>
              <description>
                 <li>CI = ***CI***</li>
                 <li>LONGITUDE = ***LONGITUDE***</li>
                 <li>LATITUDE = ***LATITUDE***</li>
              </description>
              <Point>
                <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                <coordinates>***LONGITUDE***,***LATITUDE***,***SCALE***</coordinates>
              </Point>
            </Placemark>
          </Document>
          <Document>
            <name>LINES</name>
            <Style id="myDefaultStyles">
            </Style>
            <Placemark>
              <name>***SITE ID***</name>
              <styleUrl>#myDefaultStyles</styleUrl>
              <MultiGeometry>
                <LineString>
                  <gx:drawOrder>3</gx:drawOrder>
                  <coordinates>***LONGITUDE***,***LATITUDE***,***SCALE***</coordinates>
                </LineString>
              </MultiGeometry>
            </Placemark>
          </Document>
        </Folder>
      </Folder>
    </Folder>
  </Folder>
</kml>
```

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME1 = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("region", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("technology", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("sitetype", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("status", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("siteid", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("cellid", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("LONGITUDE", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("LATITUDE", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("SCALE", typeof(double));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "G", "MACRO", "WORKING", "2330", 23301, 24.4251, 25.6011, 87 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "G", "MACRO", "WORKING", "2330", 23302, 24.4251, 25.6011, 88 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "G", "MACRO", "WORKING", "2330", 23303, 24.4251, 25.6011, 89 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "G", "MACRO", "OTHERS", "2330", 23304, 27.4251, 54.6011, 89 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "G", "MICRO", "WORKING", "2331", 23311, 25.4251, 25.6011, 90 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "G", "INDOOR", "WORKING", "2332", 23321, 26.4251, 25.6011, 87 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "U", "MACRO", "WORKING", "4330", 43301, 37.4251, 25.6011, 82 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BNGLR", "L", "MACRO", "WORKING", "5330", 53301, 19.4251, 15.6011, 80 });

            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(FILENAME1);
            XElement kml = (XElement)doc1.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ns = kml.Name.Namespace;
            XElement document = doc1.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Document").FirstOrDefault();
            string documentStr = document.ToString();

            XElement linesDoc = doc1.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Document").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
            string linesStr = linesDoc.ToString();

            kml.Element(ns + "Folder").Remove();

            var regionRows = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("region"));
            foreach (var region in regionRows)
            {
                XElement newRegion = new XElement(ns + "Folder", new object[] {
                       new XElement(ns + "name", region.Key),
                       new XElement(ns + "open", 1)
                });
                kml.Add(newRegion);

                var technologyRows = region.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("technology"));
                foreach (var technologyRow in technologyRows)
                {
                    XElement newTechnology = new XElement(ns + "Folder", new object[] {
                       new XElement(ns + "name", technologyRow.Key),
                       new XElement(ns + "open", 1)
                    });
                    newRegion.Add(newTechnology);

                    var sitetypeRows = technologyRow.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("sitetype"));
                    foreach (var siteTypeRow in sitetypeRows)
                    {
                        XElement newSiteType = new XElement(ns + "Folder", new object[] {
                           new XElement(ns + "name", siteTypeRow.Key)
                        });
                        newTechnology.Add(newSiteType);

                        var siteStatusRows = siteTypeRow.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("status"));
                        foreach (var siteStatusRow in siteStatusRows)
                        {
                            int count = 0;
                            XElement newStatus = new XElement(ns + "Folder", new object[] {
                               new XElement(ns + "name", siteStatusRow.Key)
                            });
                            newSiteType.Add(newStatus);

                            XElement pointDoc = null;
                            XElement lineDoc = null;
                            foreach (var location in siteStatusRow)
                            {
                                string newDocumentStr = documentStr;
                                newDocumentStr = newDocumentStr.Replace("***SITE ID***", location.Field<string>("siteid"));
                                newDocumentStr = newDocumentStr.Replace("***CI***", location.Field<int>("cellid").ToString());
                                newDocumentStr = newDocumentStr.Replace("***LONGITUDE***", location.Field<double>("LONGITUDE").ToString());
                                newDocumentStr = newDocumentStr.Replace("***LATITUDE***", location.Field<double>("LATITUDE").ToString());
                                newDocumentStr = newDocumentStr.Replace("***SCALE***", location.Field<double>("SCALE").ToString());

                                string newlinesStr = linesStr;
                                newlinesStr = newlinesStr.Replace("***LONGITUDE***", location.Field<double>("LONGITUDE").ToString());
                                newlinesStr = newlinesStr.Replace("***LATITUDE***", location.Field<double>("LATITUDE").ToString());
                                newlinesStr = newlinesStr.Replace("***SCALE***", location.Field<double>("SCALE").ToString());
                                newlinesStr = newlinesStr.Replace("***SITE ID***", location.Field<string>("siteid"));

                                if (++count == 1)
                                {
                                    XElement newDoc = XElement.Parse(newDocumentStr);
                                    pointDoc = newDoc;
                                    newSiteType.Add(newDoc);

                                    XElement newLineDoc = XElement.Parse(newlinesStr);
                                    lineDoc = newLineDoc;
                                    newSiteType.Add(newLineDoc);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    XElement newDoc = XElement.Parse(newDocumentStr);
                                    pointDoc.Add(newDoc.Element(ns + "Placemark"));

                                    XElement newLine = XElement.Parse(newlinesStr);
                                    lineDoc.Add(newLine.Element(ns + "Placemark"));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with this code is there is only two document section for each status and inside document section each having placemarks which should increment simultaneously for each cellids.Here document is coming outside of status and repeating everytime.Nutshell only two document for each status

Comment: see my Edited question

Comment: The li tags in 1st xml file where wrong.  Also made slight change to 2nd xml and code.

Comment: ,thanks that worked,but why document tag contains namespaces,does that makes any issues??i am testing now

Comment: Because you have the prefix 'gx' on the tag.  It may have to do with the statement : kml.RemoveAll();  If you are having issues I may need to change the RemoveAll() to something else to preserve the 'gx' namespace in the kml tag.

Comment: is there any way we can maintain same namespace structure on top which is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
 xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:json="http://www.w3.org/2005/Json">   and remove individual instances on further places

Comment: I didn't fix issue because I wasn't sure it was a problem.  Try following change.  Not exactly the same as original code. From : kml.RemoveAll(); To : kml.Element(ns + "Folder").Remove();

Comment: i will check it,but does that prevent namespace coming on succeding sides like ,each Document tag ,and for each gx tag,i will verify it ,thanks

Comment: Thats great,Now i am thinking to beautify the KML or may be while seeing on googleearth.How can i beautify the KML.I have already given styles for G,U catogarizations

Comment: You can start by spelling category correctly.  See webpage : https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata.  For all documentation see : https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/

Comment: See this webpage also : https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference

Comment: you are a champion, one more question before making answer,If i use any thirdparty dll like sharpkml etc, does that be simple or good comparing to this approach,what is the real difficulty over here?

Comment: I like using the template xml file in this case.  With the template, you can change features without changing c# code.  For example you can change font size/type or line size in the xml template and no compiling would be required (provided you added these features).  I prefer to stay with Net Library features rather than use 3rd party dlls.

Comment: @ jdweng The coloring part i have some doubt,i put the proper styling in template, but it is not coming as expected.I have to check the namespace or the schema,may be something is overriding the font and style which is set.WHat you say about this issue?

Comment: Which element on the following webpage are you using ? https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference

Comment: I will check,is there any chance of getting styles from outside XML through URL or schema.I declared styles in my KML but not affecting at all.I will give you details

Comment: You have a style tag in lines but not in points. I added an element above in points so you can modify the style as required. You can added additional styles in the elements as needed.  Also the style id and the style url have to match.  In the xml above I replaced Zamoras0_0 with myDefaultStyles.

Comment: champion work,The colour i was not getting because i have to remove # from color code.This best no third party DLL,no serialization overhead

Comment: i know it is late,but i want to know How to uncheck folders in KML file while initial loading..i have made visibility to 0 but no luck at all,still loading all data when i load with Google Earth .How to uncheck all folders and inside items so user can select which ever required in later